# why does changing axes size work differently inside and outside a function?

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

I'm working with existing code that creates a matplotlib figure with one axes, and adds a colorbar to it after-the-fact using `make_axes_locatable` and `append_axes`. It works, but I want to subsequently change the vertical height of the colorbar. I've figured out that this is only possible if I call the `set_axes_locator(None)` method on the colorbar axis (not 100% sure why) --- if I don't do that, any calls to `cax.set_position()` silently do nothing. Here's the setup; question below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colorbar import ColorbarBase
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

data = np.random.randint(4, size=(5, 7))


def make_figure(data, shrink):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(data)
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.1)
    cmap = ax.images[0].get_cmap()
    _ = ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=cmap, norm=None, orientation='vertical')
    if shrink:
        shrink_colorbar(cax)
    return fig


def shrink_colorbar(cax):
    pos = cax.get_position().bounds
    new_height = pos[-1] - 0.4
    new_y = pos[1] + 0.2
    newpos = (pos[0], new_y, pos[2], new_height)
    cax.set_axes_locator(None)
    cax.set_position(newpos)
```

If I do the colorbar resizing *inside* the function environment where the figure is created, I get the wrong result every time, whether I use regular Python REPL or iPython:

```
make_figure(data, shrink=True)
```

**WRONG RESULT:**

[image: figure with unexpectedly wide colorbar, obscuring the main plot]

If I create the figure first, then shrink the colorbar after the fact, it works how I want it to **as long as these lines are run separately** (either in regular Python REPL with `plt.ion()`, or if each line is in a separate iPython cell):

```
fig = make_figure(data, shrink=False)
cax = fig.axes[-1]
shrink_colorbar(cax)
```

**CORRECT RESULT:**

[image: figure with correctly resized colorbar]

If those same lines are run as a single iPython cell, or if run with `plt.ioff()` in a regular Python REPL and followed by `plt.show()`, I get the same bad result as the first example above (with `shrink=True` in the outer function).

**How can I get the correct result while still doing the colorbar resizing inside the function (instead of in userland)?**

Comment: Are you aware that the normal `colorbar` function has a `shrink` parameter?

Comment: yes, thanks. I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't require me to rewrite the existing code that sets up the figure and axes in the first place --- if I have to do that, I will. But if I could get an answer to the question as written, it would be an easy 6-8 line patch instead of a more complicated rewrite (the actual implementation is much more complex than this MWE).

Comment: incidentally, this is not unique to colorbars. you can plot anything you want in the right-side axes (e.g., `cax.imshow(data[:, [0]])` instead of the `ColorbarBase` line), and you still get different positioning behavior in the two cases I've shown.

Comment: Ok, I don't think I have a solution ready for you, but in general I'm not supprised that if you kill the locator (`set_axes_locator(None)`) it screws up the axes location. However, you might get away with adding `fig.canvas.draw()` before shrinking the colorbar. Though, of course, that would still be highly experimental and not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest do you know why it's necessary to kill the locator in the first place?  i.e., why, if I don't kill it, calls to cax.set_position()` don't do anything?

Comment: The locator is meant to call set_position internally based on its settings - that's its main purpose. So any position you apply externally gets overwritten at draw time. This is of course the desired behaviour.